# Unable to assign images to an imageView from an Array, but can assign images to an imageView from a UIImage variable

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, nsarray

I have a problem with arrays and passing images between views that I would like some help on!
So the background is that I have:

• RootViewController (which handles my table view)

• CommunicationViewController which handles the detail of the selected element from the table

• SelectSlideViewController which displays an image clicked on from the CommunicationViewController and allows the user to select a different one from the camera roll

So the problem:

• In the CommunicationViewConroller, I have the following code if the user clicks on a button:

```
- (IBAction) selectSlide:(id) sender
{
 if(self.selectSlideView == nil)
 {
 SelectSlideViewController *viewController = [[SelectSlideViewController alloc]
           initWithNibName:@"SelectSlideViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  self.selectSlideView = viewController;
  [viewController release];
 }

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.selectSlideView animated:YES];
 self.selectSlideView.cmn = cmn;
 self.selectSlideView.title = cmn.name;
 self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = self.myImage5;
}
```

And the above code works, if for, example, I click on button 5, as it sets image5 to the view in the “SelectSlideViewController”.

However, I would like to have multiple buttons using the same “selectSlide” action – and to do that, I need to figure out which button was pressed, and then assign the correct image to the “SelectSlideViewController” from an array of images (or a series of if-else statements which is clunky).

• So my revised code is as follows, but it doesn’t work with the array – any thoughts?:

```
- (IBAction) selectSlide:(id) sender
{
 if(self.selectSlideView == nil)
 {
 SelectSlideViewController *viewController = [[SelectSlideViewController alloc]
             initWithNibName:@"SelectSlideViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  self.selectSlideView = viewController;
  [viewController release];
 }

 NSUInteger tmpInt = -1;
 tmpInt = [buttonArray indexOfObject:sender];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.selectSlideView animated:YES];
 self.selectSlideView.cmn = cmn;
 self.selectSlideView.title = cmn.name;

 NSLog(@"The int was %d",tmpInt);
 NSLog(@"This is the image array size %d ",[imageArray count]); 

 If(tmpInt >-1 && tmpInt <9)
 {
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:tmpInt];
 }
 /** this code works, but is a bit clunky:
 if(tmpInt == 0)
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = self.myImage1;
 else if (tmpInt == 1)
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = self.myImage2;
 else if (tmpInt == 2)
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = self.myImage3;
 else if (tmpInt == 3)
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = self.myImage4;
 else if (tmpInt == 4)
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = self.myImage5;
 else if (tmpInt == 5)
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = self.myImage6;
 else if (tmpInt == 6)
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = self.myImage7;
 else if (tmpInt == 7)
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = self.myImage8;
 else if (tmpInt == 8)
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = self.myImage9; 
 **/
}
```

I have definitely confirmed that the imageArray is of size 9, and that it is picking the correct index from the array, however the SelectSlideViewController doesn't display the image, if accessed from the array. It displays it if accessed using the clunky if-else statements.

Comment: I'd like to see where you initialize and load up imageArray.

Also, unrelated, instead of  tmpInt = [buttonArray indexOfObject:sender]; you could use the tag field of the button to store the index.

Comment: Thanks mahboudz - I will look at the tag field. I have posted some code on how i load up the imageArray, further down.

For the tags - do all UI objects have to have a unique tag, or is it only important for UI objects of the same class type - i.e. all UIButtons have unique tags, but the same tag number used for UIImage (for example).

Comment: You assign the tags, they are unique if you make them unique. For example: myButton.tag = 99;

Comment: Sure, understood - but I assume that Xcode or Interface builder don't try to enforce uniqueness? It some cases it may make sense for button tags, and say associated uiimageviews to have the same tag number (for cross-referencing purposes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to the above problem (credited to "JSD" from www.iphonedevsdk.com):

Since selectSlideView.imageView  was loaded from a nib the view wasn't loaded the first time through.

I had to include the following line of code before I assigned images from my Array to the view:

```
[selectSlideView view];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load the images directly the first time, then cache afterwards. (I've excluded the caching code, and the scaling code, but you can add them after you get the image).

```
   If(tmpInt >-1 && tmpInt <9)
     {
      // Check if already cached
         self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = [self getButtonImages:tmpInt];
      // add scaling code here for smaller image

     }
```

In @implementation you can add:

```
 - (UIImage) getButtonImages:(NSInteger)index
    {   
        UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image%d.jpg", index];
        return myImage;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I will try this and get back to you - seems like a neat way of doing it. I would like to understand where I am going wrong with the arrays though. I have done Java programming before, but this Objective-C stuff is slightly different so it can get a bit confusing...

Comment: So I tried this, and it didn't work. Just so I understand the code - when this code is executed, if tmpInt = 1, is it looking for a file called myImage1, or is it looking for a variable called myImage1?

Unfortunately I havent got detail on the exception thrown at this stage. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ahh, ok - understood. The problem is that the images (other than the default one) are not stored on the filesystem. They are in a database and are retrieved an assigned to the communicationView.myImageX (where 0 < X < 10 ). So is there a way of referencing the UIImage that the myImageX is referring to? This is why I was using an array, as I could assign the image from the relevant position in the array to the UIImageView.

Comment: Didn't read your response close enough. Since the image is loaded from a database, this isn't going to work. Let me read through your code.

Comment: Hi Jordan,

Just to clarify, by caching, do you mean after retrieving the image from the database, I need to store it to the filesystem under imageX.jpg (perhaps in the "updateButtonImages" method), and then retrieve it from the filesystem in "getButtonImages"?

Comment: Any thoughts as to why I can't access the UIImage in the imageArray? It seems strange that the UIImage in the relevant index in the array does not get assigned to "self.selectSlideView.imageView.image", but that it works when I assign it to the actual variables: myImage1, myImage2 ... myImage9

Comment: My first thought was that the images in the array weren't being retained. But that doesn't seem to be the case. You sure imageArray is being retained?

Comment: In my header file, i have the following entry: @property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * imageArray;
Looks like my statement just above wasn't clear:
  UIImage myImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"];   
  [imageArray addObject:myImage1];
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = myImage1; //this works
  self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:1]; //doesn't work
 NSLog(@"This is the image array size %d ",[imageArray count]);  //this outputs value of "9"
So it could be that the imageArray is not being retained - but how do I ensure it is being retained?

Comment: Where are you doing this in your code?
imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]

Comment: Rather, this in your code, since you have it as a property. self.imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]

Comment: I allocated the imageArray in the rootController, before displaying page with the buttons. It turns out that the array method does work, however i observe the following behaviour:
- I click on a button which should diplay a new view with a larger version of the image on the button
- When I run the simulator, the first button press always results in an image not being displayed in the new view
- However if I go back and click on the same button (or indeed another button), the correct image is displayed

Only the first button press (and i have tried different buttons, but same result)

Comment: So to clarify:
1) Using arrays seems to work apart from the first button click, using the code (self.selectSlideView.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:tmpInt];)
2) I assign "imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]" in the rootViewController before displaying the view with the buttons